# Swig error with Nested enums in C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, python-2.7, swig, nested-attributes

I have a class similar to the following. It has a nested enum OptionTag.

```
class MediaPacket
{
    public:
           struct RtcpAppName {
           char mName[RTCP_APPNAME_LENGTH];
           };

          enum OptionTag {
                         RESERVED  = 0,
                         PROFILE   = 1,
                         LATENCY   = 2,
                         PKTLOSS   = 3,
                         JITTER    = 4,
                         LEGACYMIX = 5,
                         LASTTAG   = 255
                     };

                    ....
                    ....
          list<OptionTag> GetOptions(unsigned int ssrc) const;
};
```

For this I created a swig interface as follows

```
%module mediaopts_packet
%include "stdint.i"

//Redefining nested structure in swig
struct RtcpAppName {
char mName[RTCP_APPNAME_LENGTH];
};


%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "../include/mediaopts_packet.h"
%}

//nestedworkaround key for the nested struct
%nestedworkaround CRtcpAppPacket::RtcpAppName;
%{
typedef CRtcpAppPacket::RtcpAppName RtcpAppName;
%}

//Some swig definitions that are not related to this problem
//%include "carrays.i"
//%array_class(uint8_t, buffer);

//%include "typemaps.i"
//%apply (unit8_t *STRING, int LENGTH) { (uint8_t *id, uint32_t len) };
//%apply uint32_t & OUTPUT { uint32_t & xmitOpt };
//%apply uint32_t & OUTPUT { uint32_t & rcvOpt };
//%apply uint32_t & OUTPUT { uint32_t & optValue };

%include "std_list.i"

namespace std
{
    %template(ListUint32) list<uint32_t>;
    %template(ListOptionTag) list<CRtcpAppMediaoptsPacket::OptionTag>;
}

%include "../include/mediaopts_packet.h"
```

---

Using the code in python

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08)
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mediaopts_packet
>>>
>>> packet = mediaopts_packet.MediaPacket()
>>>
>>> packet.AddSSRC(0,1,1)
>>>
>>> packet.GetAllSSRC()
(0,)
>>> ssrc_list = mediaopts_packet.ListUint32()
>>>
>>> ssrc_list = packet.GetAllSSRC()
>>>
>>> ssrc_list
(0,)
>>> ssrc_list[0]
0
>>> packet.AddOption(0, mediaopts_packet.MediaPacket.RESERVED, 0)
0
>>> packet.GetOptions(0)
Segmentation fault
```

After building when I use this in python I get a segmentation fault. I am not able to understand what I missed. Please help.

Comment: What you will have to do is attach to the process with a debugger and put a break point in your C++ member function.  You can do this with Visual Studio.  Just attach to the process after you import the module that contains your C++ library.

Comment: I can't see immediately what's wrong. Can you make this a minimal but complete example? I.e. build a small test case (with a *small* .i, .h and .cpp file) that we can run in a debugger ourselves too.

Comment: Need code for AddOption. Also, what happens if drop the enum just use an int with packet.AddOption(0, 0, 0), does GetOptions(0) still cause segfault? I'd like to know if the segfault is caused by list<options> that is returned by GetOptions() being gc'd, so what if you do a = packet.GetOptions(0)?

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nested_classes) , swig does not support nested classes (they do provide some workarounds).