# How do I convert to type SWIGTYPE_p_void in SWIG generated Java bindings?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

I am developing some SWIG-generated Java bindings for a C library. The library contains functions that take parameters of type `void *`. On the C side these would typically be passed as a pointer to an array of type `float` or `int` cast to `void *`. In the generated Java bindings, this results in methods that take parameters of type `SWIGTYPE_p_void`.

What is the best way to construct an array of floats/ints in the Java bindings so that they can be passed as type `SWIGTYPE_p_void` to these methods?

At the moment I am defining a helper function in my example.i file:

```c
void *floata_to_voidp(float f[])
{
    return (void *)f;
}
```

And then on the Java side doing something like this:

```java
float foo[] = new float[2];
SWIGTYPE_p_void av = null;

// do something with foo

av = example.floata_to_voidp(foo);
example.myfunction(av);
```

This seems rather ugly, especially as I would also need an `inta_to_voidp()` etc in my SWIG interface file for each type conversion I want to support.

Is there a way to do this without helper functions and involving less extra code on the Java side to convert data types?

**UPDATE (17/6/12):** to give additional detail to the question: what I'm trying to do is take a set of C functions, with prototype `int foo(const float *data, int N, const void *argv, float *result)` and map them to methods on the Java side where an array of arbitrary type can be passed in as `argv`. Note that `argv` is `const void *` and not `void *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an alternative to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11018918/168175), it's very different and gives a more natural solution to this problem, closer to what you were looking for originally. The other suggestions were focused on adding overloads (tedious, manual) or making the `array_class`es implement a common interface one way or another.

What it overlooks is that `Object` is a good match for `void*` in Java most of the time. Even [arrays in Java are `Object`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781022/is-an-array-an-object-in-java). This means if you have SWIG map `void*` to `Object` it'll accept as inputs any arrays you might want to pass in. With a bit of care and some JNI we can then get a pointer to the start of that array to pass in to the function. Obviously we need to reject non array `Object`s with an exception though.

We still end up writing some (private) helper functions to arrange extraction of the real underlying pointer and release it when done, but the nice thing about this solution is that we only have to do this once and then we end up with a typemap that can be used for any functions which take an array as `void*` like this.

I ended up with the following SWIG interface for this solution:

```
%module test

%{
#include <stdint.h>

void foo(void *in) {
  printf("%p, %d, %g\n", in, *(jint*)in, *(jdouble*)in);
}
%}

%typemap(in,numinputs=0) JNIEnv *env "$1 = jenv;"

%javamethodmodifiers arr2voidd "private";
%javamethodmodifiers arr2voidi "private";
%javamethodmodifiers freearrd "private";
%javamethodmodifiers freearri "private";
%inline %{
jlong arr2voidd(JNIEnv *env, jdoubleArray arr) {
  void *ptr = (*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env, arr, NULL);
  return (intptr_t)ptr;
}

void freearrd(JNIEnv *env, jdoubleArray arr, jlong map) {
  void *ptr = 0;
  ptr = *(void **)&map;
  (*env)->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(env, arr, ptr, JNI_ABORT);
}

jlong arr2voidi(JNIEnv *env, jintArray arr) {
  void *ptr = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, arr, NULL);
  return (intptr_t)ptr;
}

void freearri(JNIEnv *env, jintArray arr, jlong map) {
  void *ptr = 0;
  ptr = *(void **)&map;
  (*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, arr, ptr, JNI_ABORT);
}
%}


%pragma(java) modulecode=%{
  private static long arrPtr(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof double[]) {
      return arr2voidd((double[])o);
    }
    else if (o instanceof int[]) {
      return arr2voidi((int[])o);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }

  private static void freeArrPtr(Object o, long addr) {
    if (o instanceof double[]) {
      freearrd((double[])o, addr);
      return;
    }
    else if (o instanceof int[]) {
      freearri((int[])o, addr);
      return;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
%}

%typemap(jstype) void *arr "Object"
%typemap(javain,pre="    long tmp$javainput = arrPtr($javainput);",post="      freeArrPtr($javainput, tmp$javainput);") void *arr "tmp$javainput"

void foo(void *arr);
```

This implements it for two array types, there's a small finite number and you could use fragments or macros to help with this too. Internally SWIG uses a `jlong` to represent pointers. So for each array type we need a function that returns a pointer for a given array and another one to release it. These are private and part of the module class - nobody other than the module needs to know how this works.

There's then two functions which take the `Object` and use `instanceof` (ugly, but arrays in Java don't have any other common base or interface and generics don't help) and call the correct function to get/release the pointers.

With these then it's just two typemaps to set up SWIG to use it for all `void *arr` arguments. The jstype typemap instructs SWIG to use `Object` for `void*` in these cases. The javain typemap arranges for a temporary local variable to hold the pointer (in a `long`) and then for it to be used to make the call and to be cleaned up once the call has succeed or failed.

Comment: This is a very nice technique indeed, and your test code works perfectly. It *almost* works for me in context except for the detail that my C functions actually take `const void *` and not `void *`. I can avoid writing wrapper functions with `%apply void *in {const void *argv};`, but unless I redeclare all of my functions (there are 50!), as taking `void *`, I get: _Can't apply (void *in). No typemaps are defined_. Is there any way I can just tell "treat `const void *` as `void *`"?

Comment: @JamieBullock I think you're probably using `%apply` in the wrong place. You need to use it *after* all the typemaps have been defined. So I added `%apply void *arr { const void *argv }` at the end of the interface and it worked fine. You also need to be careful to match the parameter names exactly if you're matching on that - my example had them called `arr` but the `%apply` you showed calls it `in`, not sure if that's because you renamed it all though.

Comment: that doesn't work for me, but you are right `%apply void *in {const void *argv};` was erroneous. in the end I decided to make a 1 line script in my build script to generate a redeclare.i with all of my functions redeclared as taking `void *` instead of `const void *`, and then added `%include redeclare.i` to the end of my main `.i` file. Maybe not so elegant, but it does work. This combined with your solution above now lets me freely pass Java arrays as void *, which is great. Thanks!

Comment: @JamieBullock perhaps I should have been more explicit - the `%apply` in [this modified version of my answer](http://pastie.org/4113434) generated the right Java interface.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to [use SWIG's `<carrays.i>` to make a type that wraps an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10495755/168175) of `float` and an array of `int` and any other types you care about. These can be converted to `SWIGTYPE_p_float` etc. trivially using the `cast()` member function. The problem is that this can't automatically be converted to a `SWIGTYPE_p_void` from within Java. You could in theory call:

```
new SWIGTYPE_p_void(FloatArray.getCPtr(myfloatarr));
```

but for various reasons (not least it's cumbersome) that's less than ideal. (It also has issues with memory ownership and garbage collection).

So instead I defined an interface:

```
public interface VoidPtr {
  public long asVoidPtr();
}
```

That we can make the wrapped version of your library take as input and the array classes `FloatArray`, `IntArray` etc. implement for us.

This ends up with the module file:

```
%module test

%include <carrays.i>

%typemap(javainterfaces) FloatArray "VoidPtr"
%typemap(javainterfaces) IntArray "VoidPtr"

%typemap(javacode) FloatArray %{
  public long asVoidPtr() {
    return getCPtr(this);    
  }
%}

%typemap(javacode) IntArray %{
  public long asVoidPtr() {
    return getCPtr(this);
  }
%}

%array_class(float, FloatArray);
%array_class(int, IntArray);

%typemap(jstype) void *arr "VoidPtr"
%typemap(javain) void *arr "$javainput.asVoidPtr()"

void foo(void *arr);
```

Which modifies `void *arr` to be treated as our `VoidPtr` type and automatically calls the `asVoidPtr()` method. You could use [typemap copying](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn13) or macros to make this less repetitive. (Note, there's a possible issue with [premature garbage collection](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_pgcpp) that might need to be addressed here depending on how you planned to use this)

This allows us to write code like:

```
public class run {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    FloatArray arr = new FloatArray(100);
    test.foo(arr);    
  }
}
```

I think this is the easiest, cleanest solution. There are several other ways you could solve this though:

1. It's also possible to write some code that would take an actual Java array rather than just the SWIG `array_class` and implement this interface by calling a JNI function to obtain the underlying pointer. You'd have to write a version of this for every primitive type though, just like the above.

   An interface file could then look something like:

   ```
   %module test

   %{
   void foo(void *arr);
   %}

   %typemap(in,numinputs=0) JNIEnv *env "$1 = jenv;"

   %rename(foo) fooFloat;
   %rename(foo) fooInt;
   %inline %{
   void fooFloat(JNIEnv *env, jfloatArray arr) {
     jboolean isCopy;
     foo((*env)->GetFloatArrayElements(env, arr, &isCopy));
     // Release after call with desired semantics
   }

   void fooInt(JNIEnv *env, jintArray arr) {
     jboolean isCopy;
     foo((*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, arr, &isCopy));
     // Release after call
   }
   %}

   void foo(void *arr);
   ```

   Which then gives you overloads of `foo` which take `float[]` and `int[]` as well as `SWIGTYPE_p_void`.
2. You could use a trick with a union:

   ```
   %inline %{
     union Bodge {
       void *v;
       float *f;
       int *i;
     };
   %}
   ```

   although this is considered bad form, it does generate you a Java interface that can be used to convert from `SWIGTYPE_p_int` to `SWIGTYPE_p_void`.
3. I think it's possible to make `FloatArray` inherit from `SWIGTYPE_p_void`, something like the following compiled but untested code:

   ```
   %module test

   %include <carrays.i>

   %typemap(javabase) FloatArray "SWIGTYPE_p_void"
   %typemap(javabody) FloatArray %{
     private long swigCPtr; // Minor bodge to work around private variable in parent
     private boolean swigCMemOwn;
     public $javaclassname(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
       super(cPtr, cMemoryOwn);
       this.swigCPtr = SWIGTYPE_p_void.getCPtr(this);
       swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
     }
   %}

   %array_class(float, FloatArray);

   void foo(void *arr);
   ```

   This duplicates the pointer on the Java side, but nothing changes that (currently) in either the void pointer or array classes so that's not as big a problem as it first seems. (You could also make it protected in the base class with an alternative typemap I think, or use a modified version of `carrays.i` that gets `swigCPtr` via the `getCPtr` function instead)